# Git Checkout a file from remote branch with history

Tags: git

I am merging one project to another project using merge and while merging some of the files are deleted due to conflict and I am able to checkout the file from branch I temporarily created but I need to maintain the history. Is it possible to checkout a file with history.

Steps followed

```
git remote add tmpmerge <giturl>
git fetch tmpmerge
git merge tmpmerge/branch --allow-unrelated-histories
```

While following above steps some files are deleted (10 files & totally 327 files).

I want to checkout the file from temp branch tmpmerge/branch with history and I can able to checkout the file using below command

```
git checkout tmpmerge/branch -- <filepath>
```

I need to checkout the file with history . Please let me know is it possible to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do *you* mean by "a file with history"? In Git, history is defined as "a series of commits"—not files but *commits*. Commits contain files, so history (which is commits) contain files. Files aren't history by themselves.

Comment: I want to copy the code with commit history and By merge I can able to achieve it but not by checkout . Is there any other way for it.

Comment: The file will still have all of that history. e.g. `git log path/to/deleted/file` will still show you everything that happened to that file.

Comment: The "commit history" is the set of commits. Add a new commit, and you have added more history. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot checkout some file like SVN or CVS, but you can see them with `git show [commit]:[file]`

**Example** 
`git show c50ec5a:./src/main/java/com/demo/myx/DemoServiceApplication.java` to retrieve `DemoServiceApplication.java` on commit `c50ec5a`.

by this result you can append `> file_output` for save result to `file_output` like `git show c50ec5a:./src/main/java/com/demo/myx/DemoServiceApplication.java > file_output`

and you can use `gitk --follow [file]` to retrieve file full history.
**Example** 
`gitk --follow ./src/main/java/com/demo/myx/DemoServiceApplication.java`.